# Excel Web Import Date recognition

Tags: excel, date, web, import

I would like to know if it's possible to set the Date format only for certain columns. The problem is when I set the Format after downloading the Data from Web it will reset when I Update the Data. But when I keep the Date recognition on it will format Numbers like 9-17 that's what I don't want to...

```
Column 1  | Column 2
  Dates   | No Dates
```

Comment: what kind of source are you using? TFS doesn't allow re-formatting b/c it thinks that you are attempting to change the data-type in the source.  You may want to create a macro to re-format each time after you update the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the column header of the column with the right mouse button and select Format Cells... A dialog box will appear where there is a tab labelled "Number" where you can set the date format for that column. You can alse select multiple columns holding the Ctrl button while you click them and you can apply the same date format for all those columns.

Comment: Thx for your reply! The problem is that as soon as i update the content the format is switching back.